# Как посчитать пройденное расстояние на автомобиле

Tags: android, ios, flutter

Я в будущем хочу разработать мобильное приложение которая считает сколько метров я проездил на своей машине, таких программ полно, но я хочу понять КАК!? делаятся как программа считает сколько метров сколько километров на своей машине проехался, знаю что мне поможет геолокация но как там с алгоритмами, кто меня понял спасибо. Язык программирование Flutter

Comment: Начните с такого - через определённые интервалы времени получайте координаты и считайте расстояние от предыдущей точки.

Comment: Гуглите *теорему гаверсинусов*.

Comment: @MarkShevchenko никаких теорем не надо знать, там всё в сдк есть, просто нужные методы повызывать и у тебя все в метрах будет.

Comment: @Maxgmer можно примеры пожалуйста

Comment: Есть пример в книге "Head First. Программирование для Android", https://www.piter.com/collection/all/product/head-first-programmirovanie-dlya-android

Comment: @Style-7 на Flutter пробовали?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Обычно это делается так - приложение подписывается на обновления о локации, которые приходят от ОС, которая получает их от железа. Эти обновления - значения широты и долготы.

Как это работает в вашем примере: когда машина едет и девайс получает координаты, ваше приложение считает расстояние между последними и предпоследними полученными координатами с помощью некоторых вычислений (как подсказал Mark Shevchenko, используется https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula). С каждыми новыми координатами это расстояние снова считается и полученные метры суммируются.

Как получить эти координаты и расстояние между ними?
В случае с Flutter мы можем подключить эту [библиотеку](https://pub.dev/packages/geolocator) и получать координаты так:

```
Position pos = await Geolocator().getLastKnownPosition(desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.high);
```

Получаем расстояние в метрах мы так:

```
double distanceInMeters = await Geolocator().distanceBetween(prevPos.latitude, prevPos.longitude, pos.latitude, pos.longitude);
```